# "Invalid label" when calling jsonip.com with jQuery with jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, jsonp

I'm going absolutely crazy... I keep getting an "invalid label" error in Firebug when executing this simple piece of Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://jsonip.com",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("success!")
    }
  });
});
```

Firebug will say (in the console tab):

```
Invalid label
{"ip":"99.99.99.99"}
```

with a pointer to the first double quotes (IP address mocked for obvious reasons).

The call in in the net tab is what one would expect: `http://jsonip.com/?callback=jQuery17108684927028894522_1326752040735&_=1326752042159`, so the callback parameter is in place too.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1. I have also tried this with jQuery 1.6.4 but without success.

Anyone...? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify a JSONP callback to jsonip.com you must to put the callback name like this:

```
http://jsonip.com/{theCallback}
```

To do this with jQuery, there are some simple configurations to the `ajax` method. This code works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://jsonip.com/theCallbackFunction",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "theCallbackFunction",

        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.ip);
        }
    });
});
```

Regards!

Comment: Ah, good stuff, though this will have unexpected results if you do the request again before the previous request returned (not that there's any good reason why you would).

Comment: Oh darn.... these are typical late night oversights. The format I was sending out was indeed `http://jsonip.com/callback=theCallbackFunction` and I needed to ditch the `callback=`. Thanks @eagleoneraptor!

Answer (score 1):

The callback function seems to be passed as a url fragment. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmyBf/1)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the answer by eagleoneraptor and the comment by  lonesomeday:

You may create a dynamic name for the callback-function on the fly and append that name to the url:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://jsonip.com/",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback:function(){var fnc='cb'+$.now();this.url+=fnc;return fnc;},
    jsonp:false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data.ip)
    }
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/YfHYs/

Answer (score 0):

I run jsonip.com.

The service now supports:

1. CORS
2. path callbacks, http://jsonip.com/myfunc => myfunc({"ip":""})
3. parameter callbacks, http://jsonip.com/?callback=myfunc => myfunc({"ip":""})

Note that for the parameter callbacks, ?callback is required. "myfunc" can, of course, be whatever you want.

See http://jsonip.com/about for details.